# Show that if $F$ is continuous, then it is continuous in each variable separately.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Can someone please verify my proof? I am aware that there may be a similar question posted elsewhere, but I need help with my proof in particular.

$\textbf{Note:}$ This is not homework.

> Let $F: X \times Y \longrightarrow Z$. We say that $F$ is continuous in each variable separately if for each $y_0 \in Y$, the map $h: X \longrightarrow Z$ defined by $h(x) = F(x, y_0)$ is continuous, and for each $x_0 \in X$, the map $k: Y \longrightarrow Z$ defined by $k(y) = F(x_0, y)$ is continuous. Show that if $F$ is continuous, then $F$ is continuous in each variable separately.

We show that $h$, as defined above, is continuous. It can similarly be proven that $k$ is continuous.

Let $U \subseteq Z$ be open. Then, $$h^{-1}(U) = \{x : (x, y_0) \in F^{-1}(U)\}$$

Let $(X, y_0)$ denote the set $\{(x, y_0): x \in X\}$. Clearly, $F^{-1}(U) \cap (X, y_0)$ is open in $(X, y_0)$ under the subspace topology. Now, note that $(X, y_0)$ is homeomorphic to $X$, with homeomorphism $f:(X, y_0) \longrightarrow X$ defined by $f(x) = x$. So, $$f(F^{-1}(U) \cap (X, y_0))$$
is open in $X$. But this set is precisely $h^{-1}(U)$. Therefore, $h$ is continuous.

Comment: $F:X\longrightarrow Y$ or $F:X\times Y\longrightarrow Z$?

Comment: @Pedro Yes, you are right. I've just fixed it.

Comment: The notation $(X,y_0)$ is not common, one usually writes $X\times\{y_0\}$, and the map $f$ should read $f(x,y_0)=x$. But apart from that, your proof is perfect.